# Displaying address of pointer variable using & operator

Tags: c, pointers

What will be the difference between output of the two `printf` functions in the following program. Should output of both be same or not?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main() {
      int *p;
      printf("%p",&p);
      printf("\n%p",p);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: Try compile and run => Think about why => Ask a question if you don't understand.

Comment: One is the address referenced by "p". The other is the address of the space used by the variable "p" to store that address.

Comment: Yes, the wording of the question is not great, but would Sarao have gotten all these down-votes if the question had been phrased as "Why don't these two statements print the same thing"? Poor kid's going to be scared off from using pointers for life. :)

Answer (score 1):

- `&p` - The address of the pointer
- `p` - The address pointer by the pointer
- `*p` -The *content* inside the address pointer by the pointer

Answer (score 1):

Here the pointer p is declared but not initialized so would be pointing toward an unknown memory location. Program should give a compile error. However if you use indirection operator(*), it will give you the value of the memory location accosiated with p( Garbbage Value in this case). & operator is used to find the address associated with a variable.

Suggested Modification in program:

```
int main() {
   int *p;
   printf("%u",*p);
   printf("\n%u",p);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

some random value(garbage value)

Memory location of p

Comment: WTF? Accessing *p when p contains random garbage is even worse than the code in the OP. Assuming 4 byte ints, the odds are 3 in 4 that the value of p is not divisible by 4, so accessing *p will cause an alignment fault.

Answer (score 0):

The first outputs the address of a variable in the current stack frame.

The second outputs an uninitialized value; you should turn up your compiler warnings until it complains.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

- `printf("%p", p);` will print the value of `p`, that is, the address of the int it points at. (Though, in your example, you don't initialize it to point at anything in particular.)
- `printf("%p", &p);` will print the address of `p`, which is not so useful.